# sqlplus set explicit time

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am using the following query to extract data. But, I want the time to be exact instead of variable.

```
WHERE DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.REPORT_TIMESTAMP <= SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3' HOUR + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE 
AND DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.REPORT_TIMESTAMP >=   SYSTIMESTAMP  - INTERVAL '3' HOUR - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
```

I want the time to be given like this:

```
where REPORT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2016-08-11 20:59:00' AND '2016-08-11 20:59:01'
```

The time is a constant, but the date always points to yesterday, that's why I used the first query. is there anyway to mix both?

Comment: So you want date to be yesterday and time to  be exactly  between 20:59:00 and 20:59:01 ? Have I understood you correctly ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Time stamp between yesterday's date, time between 20:59:00 and 20:59:01.

Functions used: [to_timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) , [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) , [sysdate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)

```
where REPORT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN 

TO_TIMESTAMP (to_char(sysdate-1,'DD-Mon-RR')  || ' 20:59:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS') 

and

TO_TIMESTAMP (to_char(sysdate-1,'DD-Mon-RR')  || ' 20:59:01', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: @Sam to_timestap function returns time stamp based on char  input and format. The time part of the input string is constant ' 20:59:00'  or '20:59:01'. To generate yesterday's date as char  I use (sysdate-1) and then convert it to character string with given format - by using to_char function.